# Strange output dsolve matlab

Tags: matlab, diff, equation, dsolve

I'm trying to solve a differential equation, but the output shows the result in two lines, what does it mean?

```
clear
clc

syms g(t) a b c a0 q V calculated_gamma tox kb T Vel0 Ea t1 c0 k1

eqn = diff(g,t) == -Vel0 * exp(-Ea*q/(kb*T))*sinh(a0*q*V*calculated_gamma/(tox*kb*T)-a0*q*V*c0/(tox*kb*T)*g);

pretty (eqn)

S = dsolve(eqn)

pretty (S)
```

Command Window:

```
 d                   / V a0 calculated_gamma q   V a0 c0 q g(t) \    /   Ea q \
-- g(t) == -Vel0 sinh| ----------------------- - -------------- | exp| - ---- |
dt                   \         T kb tox             T kb tox    /    \   T kb /


S =

                                                                                                                      calculated_gamma/c0
 -(T*kb*tox*log(exp(-(V*a0*calculated_gamma*q)/(T*kb*tox))*tanh((V*a0*c0*q*(C5 - Vel0*t*exp(-(Ea*q)/(T*kb))))/(2*T*kb*tox))))/(V*a0*c0*q)

/                                          calculated_gamma                                          \
|                                          ----------------                                          |
|                                                 c0                                                 |
|                                                                                                    |
|               /                                      /           /                /   Ea q \ \ \ \ |
|               |                                      | V a0 c0 q | C5 - Vel0 t exp| - ---- | | | | |
|               |    /   V a0 calculated_gamma q \     |           \                \   T kb / / | | |
|   T kb tox log| exp| - ----------------------- | tanh| --------------------------------------- | | |
|               \    \           T kb tox        /     \                2 T kb tox               / / |
| - ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
\                                               V a0 c0 q                                            /
```

I appreciate any answers, many thanks.

Comment: What are you actually asking here? It is an equation, it defines relationships between variables... what were you expecting as an output, and how does that differ from what you're getting? What isn't clear or is unexpected about this output? What are you trying to achieve? This question is currently too broad, and primarily opinion based (both off-topic).

Comment: @wolfie if you see the output from 'S' it shows 2 diferent lines:

"calculated_gamma/c0" 

and 

"-(T*kb*tox*log(exp(-(V*a0*calculated_gamma*q)/(T*kb*tox))*tanh((V*a0*c0*q*(C5 - Vel0*t*exp(-(Ea*q)/(T*kb))))/(2*T*kb*tox))))/(V*a0*c0*q)"

my question is: whats the relationship between these 2 lines? it is clearly shown in the 'pretty' result too, one line is above and the other below but, I don't know how to interpretate that.

Comment: You've got a function in two variables, I assume this is the relationship of your two variables...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think that this makes no sense. As a result of the equation we should get one single answer, one single line of command. The original function doesn't depend of two variables, it's just a differential equation.

Comment: The equation `dy/dt = 3` is "just a differential equation", the solution to which is `y = 3t ( + c )`. This is an equation in two variables. I do not know if this is the answer to your question (hence why I posted a comment and not an answer), but "makes no sense" undermines your gratitude when the full sentiment is "makes no sense [to me]".